# Populate textboxes from SQL Datasource Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a database that has data like first name, last name, address, etc. I would like to be able to use my stored procedure I created. Here is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Edituser
@uid int
AS
Select * From Contacts
Where UserID=@uid
```

Now on my page in Visual Studio I create a SQLDatasource, link it to that Stored Procedure, and then how do I populate text boxes with that data that it has retrieved? I am not sure if I should use like the reader and do a loop maybe, im not sure so hopefully someone can help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [`DetailsView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx) or a [`FormView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) and bind the columns to the appropriate display controls.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to click on the control you want to data bind in design view, click the arrow to expand options, and select "Choose data source..." Your SqlDataSource should show up on there, just choose it and then the fields you want to display or use. (You may need to click "Refresh schema" at the bottom).

Alternatively, you can bind controls to data sources programatically:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "foo";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "bar";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Or, you can do the query manually like reggie shows if you need to manipulate or remove some data before binding it directly to a control.